# Using Rhodes Plugin changes loop length in MPC Beats

Tags: learning, midi, daw

In a tutorial how to create a [simple House Track](https://youtu.be/nrjE2blCevY) , I use MPC Beats with an AKAI MPK mini. If you start MPC Beats you'll be asked to open a template or your stuff. I chose open a House template. And followed the video closely until at around 2:00.

Then I tried to add a Rhodes Chorus (including all settings) as to be seen in the link above and noticed, that when I redo the shown pattern and hit the pads, that the loop restarts at zero before I could complete the whole chords (like pad 5 for 1sec, pad 4 for 1 sec, pad 2 for 1 sec, 1/8 pause and hit again for a quarter sec). I am only able to hit 2 pads, then the loop restarts at cycle zero.

Does anyone know why that happens and does one know to adjust the loop length to the length of all other tracks?

Comment: I found out, that I could add more "Bars" from 2 to 4, then copy everything and move the timeframe cursor to the correct rectangle and paste. This could give me more time to complete the mentioned pattern of my question...

Comment: Please write that as an answer, and then you can accept your own answer. This site is designed to have _questions_ and _answers_, and you wrote that in a "comment", not an "answer".

Comment: Thank you. I am waiting for possible better answers. I wanted to write this as an interim status of my efforts.

Comment: It seems like a very specific issue. Is the problem that the track is too short? Have you read the MPC Beats software manual and are you familiar with the basic concepts like track and sequence? The manual can be accessed from the software itself, Menu > Help > MPC Beats Help > MPC Beat Software Manual. Find out what "track length" and sequence length" mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Edit|Sequence|Double Length to copy the entire track to the right.

Or, if you want to repeat a subset of the loop, select the bars you want to copy, hit Ctrl+C and move the timeline marker where you'd like to paste, and hit Ctrl+V as many times as you want to copy bars.

If you want to extend all the tracks, go into Track View, copy the bars for all the tracks and paste similar to the paragraph above.